# SharePoint 2013 IE8 CSWP Trimming text by default

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, content-search-web-part

I have a Content Search WebPart which displays a single line text field on it. It shows up fine in IE10 but when I open it up in IE8, it automatically trims the text to about 50 characters.

How can I stop the behaviour of IE8.

Comment: Have you investigated the display template to see if there is conditional logic?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Yes I have and there is no logic

Comment: Sorry, it's not something I can easily test. One approach you might take is to look at the CSS in IE8 using IE debug tools.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott I have checked that as well. There are no conditions.